# Mass/Batch renaming text files based on the first line (content) of the text file in Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: files, text, rename, batch

I have 2015 files which are `.pgn` files. This is a form of text file only, opens with Notepad++. I am I want to mass rename these files replacing their name with the first line of the respective file content in Ubuntu 20.10. How can we achieve this task?

[image]

This is the sample file. The file name is `eco_1.pgn` and I want this to change to the first line of file content which is shown in the picture This I wish to do for all the 4030 files I have at once in one operation if possible. Is there any easy way to mass rename based on file content(first line) for this? If someone can help, I thank them very much. Thanks. :)

**Edit:**

There are 2015 files in total. Existing names of the files are `eco_1.pgn, eco_2.pgn, ........` up to `eco_2015.pgn`
I want to rename each and every of these files to match exactly the first line of respective file content. A sample file is shown in the image in which the first line is:

```
[ECO "A00"] [Opening "Polish (Sokolsky) opening"]
```

So the name of this file should change from `eco_1.pgn` to `[ECO "A00"] [Opening "Polish (Sokolsky) opening"]`

Each and every file is a `.pgn` file (This is a type of simple text file, it is Portable Game Notation used for entering chess moves). `.pgn` files can be saved as `.txt` files also without any issues. But I do not want to change the extension here. Only changing of names is required, replacing it with first line of the file content for all 2015 files. Thank you. :)

Comment: Please add extra info with examples of some of the current file names and the desired target names. Do you want to keep the extensions? what kind of files, text, images ...etc? add all that in text and not screenshots. [edit] your question to add that. You can start with a for loop from the directory containing the files like `for f in *; do echo "$f"; done` add the commands you wish to do on the file after `echo "$f";` like so  `first command;` then `second command;` ...and report back on how this goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename all the files at once, use `head` to get the first line in the file and `mv` to rename the file with a **for** loop like so:

```
for f in *.pgn
    do
    f1=$(head -n1 "$f")
    echo mv -n "$f" "$f1"
    done
```

Run the above from within the directory containing the files to see a dry-run (no actual renaming will happen).

**When satisfied with the results**, remove `echo` to do the actual renaming like so:

```
for f in *.pgn
    do
    f1=$(head -n1 "$f")
    mv -n "$f" "$f1"
    done
```

---

**Notice:**

The first line in each file must be unique or otherwise some files will get overwritten. That is why I added the option `-n` after `mv` to prevent that.

If however the first line in each file is not unique, you can make `mv` append numbers to the new file names if they already exist by using the option `--backup=t` after `mv` like so:

Change this line in the above code:

```
echo mv -n "$f" "$f1"
```

To this:

```
echo mv --backup=t "$f" "$f1"
```

`echo` is there to protect your files from unintentional change while testing the code and to give you a dry-run of what will actually happen. **Remove** `echo` for the actual renaming to happen.

Also note that the actions of the `mv` options (`-n` or `--backup=t`) will not be reflected in the output while `echo` is used but will take effect when `echo` is removed.

One more thing is if the first line in the file contains slashes `/` this is not acceptable and will result in an error so you need to redefine the variable `$f1` and change them to underscores `_` by adding this line to the code after `f1=$(head -n1 "$f")`:

```
f1="${f1//\//_}"
```

The final working code that can take care of duplicate file names and slashes is this ( **be careful** this will rename files immediately **not a dry-run**):

```
for f in *.pgn
    do
    f1=$(head -n1 "$f")
    f1="${f1//\//_}"
    mv --backup=t "$f" "$f1"
    done
```

Comment: When I enter the first command I get the following output:   .................................................... 
mv -n eco_999.pgn [ECO "C39"] [Opening "KGA"] [Variation "Allgaier, Walker attack"]
mv -n eco_99.pgn [ECO "A13"] [Opening "English"] [Variation "Neo-Catalan"]
mv -n eco_9.pgn [ECO "A00"] [Opening "Grob"] [Variation "Fritz gambit"]
This happens without any name change. I do not understood how to remove echo so I typed remove echo in terminal and pressed enter after this. Name change did not happen.

Comment: Then I only typed echo in terminal and pressed enter. Then also nothing happened. Each and every file is unique. I operated the first for loop command first as you suggested me. If there is any more information I am ready to provide it. Thank you very much for attempting to solve this problem I am facing, Many thanks.

Comment: @Maverick You don't type "remove echo" in the terminal ... copy and paste the code in a text editor then use the backspace key to remove, delete or erase the word **`echo`** from the command after that copy and paste in the terminal and renaming will happen. **make sure you are in the right directory first** which you seem to be in by looking at the output in your comment. If you need help, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: @Maverick I updated the answer with code without the `echo`. So copy and paste that to do the renaming. Some people tend to copy, paste and run commands to test them in directories that have important data and they do not pay attention. So I added `echo` which will print the output on the screen but no harm done to files... that's why.

Comment: Many again for helping me. I did exactly as you suggested me. I was able to convert most names but only some gave some errors and did not change names. The output of the second command (one without echo) in my next comment because there is character limit in comment section stopping me from post entire output at once. You are very knowledgeable. :)

Comment: Output of second command:        mv: cannot move 'eco_1317.pgn' to '[ECO "C60"] [Opening "Ruy Lopez"] [Variation "fianchetto (Smyslov/Barnes) defence"]': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'eco_1378.pgn' to '[ECO "C70"] [Opening "Ruy Lopez"] [Variation "Taimanov (chase/wing/accelerated counterthrust) variation"]': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'eco_2011.pgn' to '[ECO "E97"] [Opening "King'\''s Indian"] [Variation "orthodox, Aronin-Taimanov variation (Yugoslav attack / Mar del Plata variation)"]': No such file or directory             I have shortened the output.

Comment: This is the original file link : https://github.com/dmarce1/MorphyChess/blob/master/eco.pgn                        This is the file I have managed with your help for bring it to: https://we.tl/t-GrWjOUrdj9

Comment: I have successfully changed the few errors manually. Thank you very very much. :) It was very helpful to me.

Comment: @Maverick I checked https://we.tl/t-GrWjOUrdj9 . **93** files were not renamed of which **87** had duplicate first lines **not unique** and I used the option `--backup=t` instead of `-n` took care of that and they were renamed successfully. The remaining **6** files had slashes in the first line which is not acceptable in a file name but can be solved. I will update the answer with that.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much to you. You are saying the right thing. Your answer has been very helpful to me. In fact it solved my problem so well. I wish I had 10% of knowledge you have in coding. Those having slashes I solved by manually removing all slashes. There were some duplicates which I removed. Then I saw the file name was associated with wrong pair but it was not the fault of your code, it was the fault of the database so I rectified the database a bit and used your code again and I now have all the files perfectly with me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Maverick No problem .... I wish I had 10% of the knowledge you have in chess :)

Comment: hahaha. :) Not a very good player, just above average. I wanted to separate these ECO codes because it was not done before, at least not that I know of. After this I have only one major operation left to do is to mass convert all these .pgn files to .bin format books using a very small script made by someone. But I can only do one at a time. I am in doubt if I should ask that as a new question or ask at all, also would it be considered relevant to Ask Ubuntu to ask such a question. It will help a lot of Chess Players playing at Playchess & Infinity Chess and make Chess book authors' life easy.

Comment: @Maverick Yes, asking questions about file formats on Ubuntu and how to convert  and deal with them is relevant on this site. Feel free to post a new question anytime.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this. I will form a very good question now with as may details as possible to get the best answer. It will also help others to reach solution with their problems related to this in this same domain. Thank you. :)